# Create folder with PC Serial Number and redirect log text file in it using batch script

Tags: batch, batch-file

Trying to Create folder with PC Serial Number and redirect log text file in it. If folder exist then override it. Script is executing without any error but unable to fulfill my requirement

Code i'm trying:

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber') do call :Sub %%a
set "myDIR= %SerialNumber%"

if exist "C:\%myDIR%" (
    mkdir "C:\%myDIR% (2)" 2> Test.txt
) else (
    mkdir "C:\%myDIR%" 2> Test.txt
)
Pause
goto :eof

:Sub
if not "%*"=="" set SerialNumber=%*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Script is executing without any error but unable to fulfil my requirement

Observations:

1. You have a space in

   ```
   set "myDIR= %SerialNumber%"
   ```

   It should be

   ```
    set "myDIR=%SerialNumber%"
   ```
2. `mkdir` does not output anything, it sets the `errorlevel`

   > If the Directory was successfully created `%ERRORLEVEL%` = `0`
   >
   > If the > Directory could not be created `%ERRORLEVEL%` = `1`

   Source: [MD - Make directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html)

   This means that `Test.txt` is created in the directory where the script is run, but it is an empty file.
3. You haven't specified any requirements.

   With the above observations the script will create the appropriate directories and an empty text file.

   You haven't said what else it should do.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)